# Unable to install pg gem (Rails 3 - Cygwin) - sh: : command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, cygwin, sh

When I run

```
$ gem install pg
```

I get the following

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-pg
        --without-pg
        --with-pg-dir
        --without-pg-dir
        --with-pg-include
        --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
        --with-pg-lib
        --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
        --with-pg-config
        --without-pg-config
        --with-pg_config
        --without-pg_config


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.15.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.15.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

When I run

```
$ gem install pg -- --with-pg-config= /cygdrive/c/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin/pg-config
```

I get the following

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-pg-config= /cygdrive/c/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin/pg-config
Using config values from
sh: : command not found
sh: : command not found
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-pg
        --without-pg
        --with-pg-dir
        --without-pg-dir
        --with-pg-include
        --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
        --with-pg-lib
        --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
        --with-pg-config


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.15.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.15.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

What does the "**sh: : command not found**" mean?

Is this the reason why the installation is failing?

Background:

- I am using Cygwin
- I used the one click installer of PostgreSQL
- The pg_config.exe file is located at C/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin/pg-config.exe
- The libpq-fe.h file is located at C/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/include/libpq-fe.h

Comment: Thanks for writing a good, clear, and detailed question that made it immediately clear what was wrong and why. I'd +5 if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix and match native Windows code and Cygwin code. If you want to link to `libpq` you'll need the *cygwin* build `libpq` and you'll need to make sure the version of `pg_config` found on the `PATH` is the cygwin one. The `pg_config` from the native Windows build will produce output the Cygwin tools cannot understand, and even if they could they wouldn't successfully link against the native library and run with it.

As I no longer use Cygwin I can't offer any advice on the current way to install `libpq`. Presumably there's a lib in Cygwin's package management that'll be called something like `postgresql-client`, `libpq`, etc.

Cygwin is a pretty low priority platform for PostgreSQL at this point. Given that Ruby+Rails and PostgreSQL both have native Windows versions, you're setting yourself up for a hard time here, and I'd advise you to use the native versions of both tools. You can still work within a unix-like shell environment using msys bash and can use MinGW's gcc to produce native Windows executables and libraries if MSVC++ isn't an option.

Comment: The package you are looking for is `libpq-devel`.  But you should know that Rails 3.2 is already available in the [Cygwin Ports](http://cygwinports.org/) repository as `ruby-rails`.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Then

```
gem install pg
```

Comment: It's a cgywin related question, so it's a windows machine, not a Debian like